# flash CS2 where is the basic action button

Tags: flash

Select the button and in the Actions Panel (normal mode) click the plus sign and choose Basic Actions>Get URL.

But I can not locate basic action button. Where is it?

This is on a pc I'm working on.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some resources to help:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/flash_as2_learning.pdf

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/flash_as2_components_help.pdf

This will get you started.